# Get golang version from compiled binary

Tags: go

Is there a way to get golang version from `pkg/` or from compiled binary?
I want to automate removal of `$GOPATH/pkg` folder only when I change the golang version.

Comment: AFAIK starting from Go 1.5 there is no need to do it.

Comment: i'm still juggling between 1.4.3 and 1.6/1.7b1 (some projects already use 1.6+, some other bigger still using 1.4.3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind, found the answer

```
[ `strings $pkg_a_file | grep 'go object' | head -n 1 | cut -f 5 -d ' '` != `go version | cut -f 3 -d ' '` ] && \     
rm -rf $GOPATH/pkg
```

`strings $pkg_a_file | grep 'go object' | head -n 1 | cut -f 5 -d ' '` part will show something like `go1.6.2`

`pkg_a_file` can be something like this:

```
PKG_OS_ARCH=`go version | cut -d ' ' -f 4 | tr '/' '_'`
pkg_a_file=$GOPATH/pkg/$PKG_OS_ARCH/gitlab.com/kokizzu/gokil/A.a
```

External reference: http://kokizzu.blogspot.co.id/2016/06/solution-for-golang-slow-compile.html

Answer (score 2):

I found the following method, to check the version of Go lib used to compile the binary

```
$ strings compiled_binary | grep '^go1'
go1.17.4
```

Answer (score 1):

With 1.9.2, the grep command is

```
strings $pkg_a_file | grep 'Go cmd/compile'
```